# Application of Twisted Python in TCP/IP connections?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, twisted

I am writing a client that needs to establish several independent communication channels, each with its own unique port on the server, with a server through a series of sending and receiving messages. I know how to do this using socket send and recv, by giving each communication channel a socket, and do send and recv on that socket. I need to make this work in Twisted, and found potentially useful interfaces including Factory and ProcessProtocol. However, the Protocol interfaces do not provide a method to send messages. Is ProcessProtocol a good choice for my task, and how I make ProcessProtocol send messages?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here.  Do you just want to send data? Do you need discrete message boundaries? What documentation have you already read? Have you been through the Twisted tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't know about it, I'd like to give a shout out to the excellent [Twisted `finger` tutorial](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tutorial/index.html) that goes through the library at a good pace but with enough detail that you know what's going on.

To directly answer your question, though, I'd say you're on the right track with Protocol and (Client)Factory. I think the cleanest way to do what you're looking for (assuming you need to connect to different ports because they're outputs for different data) would be to make a factory/protocol pair for each port you want to connect to/handle, and then use an external class to handle the application logic aggregating all of them. Generally you wouldn't want your application logic mixed deeply with your networking logic.

A simple example: (note the use of self.transport.write to send data)

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, ClientFactory
from sys import stdout

from foobar_application import CustomAppObject

class FooProtocol(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        # Use self.transport.write to send data to the server
        self.transport.write('Hello server this is the Foo protocol.')
        self.factory.do_app_logic()

class FooFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = FooProtocol

    def __init__(self, app_object=None):
        self.app = app_object

    def do_app_logic(self):
        self.app.do_something()

class BarProtocol(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        stdout.write('Received data from server using the Bar protocol.')
        self.factory.do_fancy_logic(data)

class BarFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = BarProtocol

    def __init__(self, app_object=None):
        self.app = app_object

    def do_fancy_logic(self, data):
        self.app.do_something_else(data)

logic_obj = CustomAppObject()
reactor.listenTCP(8888, FooFactory(app_object=logic_obj)
reactor.listenTCP(9999, BarFactory(app_object=logic_obj)
reactor.run()
```

You might also want to look at the ['Writing Clients' docs on the Twisted site](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/clients.html).